# Localisation of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

> Is the ring $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,X^{-1}]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ ?

I think of the first ring as the localisation of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ at $S=\{1,X,X^{2}...\}$.
In my opinion, the localisation makes $X$ invertible and hence, the  $X$ should get canceled out.

Comment: No. It is just the ring of polynomials in $Y$ with coefficients in the ring of *Laurent polynomials* $\mathbf Q\bigl[X,X^{-1}\bigr]$. It is a U.F.D., not a P.I.D.

Comment: Why should the $X$ get cancelled out ?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,X^{-1}]/(X-1)$ ? What about $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,X^{-1}]/(X^2+1)$ ?

Comment: Dear @Maxime Ramzi, I think I was confused by quotient rings when I asked the question.

Comment: After I read @Bernard's response, everything became clear. But, how is the UFD/PID bit relevant? I'm not sure how one would show that $mathbbQ[X,X^{−1}]is a UFD. But I think neither of the two rings in the question is a PID as the former contains the latter and the latter is not a PID.

Comment: Dear @reuns, I could not get the direction you wanted my thoughts to go to. Please clarify.